# Get sub-parts of text in cell

Tags: vba, parsing, excel

I have a spreadsheet in Excel with one product per row and I would like to get the height and the width of each item according to the text in a column. I have dimensions text in the A column:

```
8" H x 8" W 
2.5" H x 3.5" W 
per side 8" H x 8" W 
1 color left side 1" H x 3" W
```

and would like to put the Height in the column (B) and the Width in the column (C). Like this:

```
              (A)                   (B)                (C)
8" H x 8" W                         8                  8
2.5" H x 3.5" W                     2.5                3.5
per side 8" H x 8" W                8                  8
1 color left side 1" H x 3" W       1                  3
```

I started with this snippet but I can't figure out how to get the desired part:

```
Sub numberExtractor()
Dim Cell As Integer
For Cell = 2 To 449

    If InStr(Cells(Cell, 17), """ H") > 0 Then
        Cells(Cell, 18).Value = Left(Cells(Cell, 17), InStr(Cells(Cell, 17), " ") - 1)
    End If
    If InStr(Cells(Cell, 17), """ W") > 0 Then
        Cells(Cell, 19).Value = Right(Cells(Cell, 17), InStr(Cells(Cell, 17), " ") + 2)
    End If

Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic:

1. Use a unique delimiter. I am using `SIDZ`.
2. Replace `" W` by `""`
3. Replace `" H x` by `SIDZ`
4. First split on `SPACE` and then on the unique delimiter

Try this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim Ar
    Dim Ht As Double, Wt As Double
    Dim sTemp As String, sDelim As String
    Dim i As Long

    sDelim = "SIDZ"

    Set rng = Range("A1:A4")

    For Each aCell In rng
        sTemp = aCell.Value
        sTemp = Replace(Replace(sTemp, """ W ", ""), """ H x ", sDelim)

        Ar = Split(sTemp)

        For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
            If Ar(i) Like "*" & sDelim & "*" Then
                aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Split(Ar(i), sDelim)(0)
                aCell.Offset(, 2).Value = Split(Ar(i), sDelim)(1)
            End If
        Next i
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It works well and I learned a lot from your example. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

With formulae, to be copied down to suit:

in B1:

```
=IF(FIND(" H",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""))>4,MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""),FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""),FIND(" H",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""))-4)+1,FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""),FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""),FIND(" H",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""))-4)+1)-FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""),FIND(" H",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""))-4)),LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""),FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""))))
```

in C1:

```
=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","")," W",""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","")," W",""))-FIND(" x ",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","")," W",""))-2)
```

[image: Photo courtesy @Siddharth Rout]

Comment: In my case I preferred the macro way but It is nice to have the adequate formula in some cases ☺ Thanks !